# How to find status and path of the specific module with C in the windows?

Tags: debugging, c, windbg, kernel-mode, driver

How to find status and path of the specific module with C in the windows?

such as windbg lm (list loaded module)

```
kd> lm m cdd
start    end       module   name
93ae0000 93afe000  cdd          (deferred)
```

I need start of module(.*sys*) but on C code

thanks

Answer (score 5):

`VirtualQueryEx()` is the way to go if you want a memory map of a target process.

However, if you want information about modules only, you can extract it from the PEB of the target process.

Get the PEB address using [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using `ProcessBasicInformation` for the `ProcessInformationClass`, so it writes a `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION`. This structure has a `PebBaseAddress` field that gives you the PEB address.

Using this PEB address, access to the [`PPEB_LDR_DATA Ldr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field, it contains a list named [`InMemoryOrderModuleList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can use to iterate through all the modules of the process.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Spl3en/9c0ea329bb7878df9b9b) is a demonstration of that technique.

Output :

```
modules.exe    : 0x00400000 -> 0x00422fff (C:\Users\Spl3en\Desktop\modules.exe)
ntdll.dll      : 0x81d20000 -> 0x81ec8fff (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
KERNEL32.DLL   : 0x7f660000 -> 0x7f798fff (C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL)
KERNELBASE.dll : 0x7f450000 -> 0x7f55dfff (C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll)
msvcrt.dll     : 0x7f970000 -> 0x7fa16fff (C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll)
```

Comment: I need this information for .sys file

Comment: @forbiddenhi that's almost the same, even simplier ! Use `SystemModuleInformation` in `ZwQuerySystemInformation`. Take a look here if you want an implementation : https://github.com/zer0box/zer0m0n/blob/master/src/driver/module.c#L89